# Edit a datatable in shiny throwing an error : Can't subset with `[` using an object of class NULL

Tags: datatable, shiny, dt

I am trying to edit a data table (DT: datatable) on server side and i am using a reactive data table which is rendered on the front end. Now i want to edit the data table and retrieve the information from edited data table. Here is a reproducible example of what i am trying to achieve as mentioned in the comments in the reprex :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

d <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(

    dataTableOutput("table1"),
    dataTableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){

    # This is the main table I would want to display in its full context
    output$table1 <- renderDataTable(
        datatable(d)
    )

    get_row <-reactive({
        d %>% slice(input$table1_rows_selected)})

    # Here the table with row selected from table 1 is displayed
    output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(get_row(),
                  editable = TRUE)
    })

    # Now as the cell gets edited in table 2, i want the edited value to show and make the last column values = NA
    proxy <- dataTableProxy("table2")

    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$table2_cell_edit, handlerExpr = {
        x <- isolate(get_row())
        info = input$table2_cell_edit
        i = info$row
        j = info$column
        v = info$value
        x[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, x[i, j])
        x <- x %>% mutate(Species = NA)
        replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE)  
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am getting an error Error in <<-: object 'x' not found. Not sure where am i wrong.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This may be a simple problem, but you're more likely to get help with a reproducible, minimal example. I'd suggest having the full app (UI and Server) that only updates an editable table (maybe with toy data). Having said all that, you might consider using `reactiveValues()` for your `data` object if you need to do the sort of assignment you're trying to do.

Comment: HI @RyanMorton Thanks for your response. I have changed the code and provided a reproducible example. Let me know if you can help

Answer (score 0):

The solution came down to your `input$table2_cell_edit` names. It uses `col` not `column`. The error created an empty `x` that couldn't accept your assignment of the new value. I used a simpler assignment of the new value.

In the future, use the `print()` function to print out variables in your app to figure out what's being passed or not passed downstream. That's how a figured out this error.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

d <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(

  dataTableOutput("table1"),
  dataTableOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  # This is the main table I would want to display in its full context
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable(
    datatable(d)
  )

  get_row <-reactive({
    req(input$table1_rows_selected)
    d %>% slice(input$table1_rows_selected)})

  # Here the table with row selected from table 1 is displayed
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    req(get_row)
    datatable(get_row(),
              editable = TRUE)
  })

  # Now as the cell gets edited in table 2, i want the edited value to show and make the last column values = NA
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("table2")

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$table2_cell_edit, handlerExpr = {
    x <- isolate(get_row())
    info = input$table2_cell_edit
    i = info$row
    ### info uses 'col' not 'column'
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    ### used a base R subset assignment 
    x[i, j] <- v
    x <- x %>% mutate(Species = NA)
    replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```